# Quisiera poder actualizar varios campos de mi tabla con un trigger cuando eliminé un paciente

Tags: trigger

Tengo una tabla pacientes en la cual aparece varios atributos uno de ellos es estado y el otro es fecha de baja,  yo quiero que cuando eliminé a un usuario lo que haga sea que me cambie el estado de activo a baja y me registre la fecha de esa modificación.
Esto lo quiero hacer con un trigger en esta misma tabla, estoy trabajando en phpmyadmin
Utilizo MySQL

Comment: Quizás leer esta documentación te es útil https://www.educba.com/sql-delete-trigger/

Comment: Que usas para el trigger? MySQL, MariaDB, SQL, etc

Comment: Para eso deberías usar un trigger que se gatille ``AFTER UPDATE`` en dicha tabla, sin mas información, es en lo que te podemos ayudar.